# Generating an array whose sum of squares of elements is equal to a given value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task: given a value N. I should generate a list of length L > 1 such that the sum of the squares of its elements is equal to N.

I wrote a code:

```
deltas = np.zeros(L)
deltas[0] = (np.random.uniform(-N, N))
i = 1
while i < L and np.sum(np.array(deltas)**2) < N**2:
    deltas[i] = (np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(N**2 - np.sum(np.array(deltas)**2)),\
                                   np.sqrt(N**2 - np.sum(np.array(deltas)**2))))
    i += 1
```

But this approach takes long time, if I generate such list many times. (I think because of loop).

Note, that I don't want my list to consist of just one unique value. The distribution of values does not have to be uniform - I took uniform just for example.

Could you suggest any faster approach? May be there is special function in any lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mind a few repeating 1s, you could do something like this:

```py
def square_list(integer):
    components = []
    total = 0
    remaining = integer

    while total != integer:
        component = int(remaining ** 0.5)
        remaining -= component ** 2
        components.append(component)
        total = sum([x ** 2 for x in components])

    return components
```

This code works by finding the taking the largest square, and then decreasing to the next largest square. It continues until the largest square is 1, which could at worse result in 3 1s in a list.

If you are looking for a more random distribution, it might make sense to randomly transform remaining as a separate variable before subtracting from it.

IE:

```py
value = transformation(remaining)
component = int(value ** 0.5)
```

which should give you more "random" values.